# Unable to start a Vue CLI project

Tags: javascript, vue-cli

I'm trying to use Vue CLI. Several months ago I could use it without a problem, but when I tried the command `npm install -g @vue/cli` just a moment ago, I got a warning `npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated`.

I tried to make a vue cli project by the command `vue init webpack-simple main-page`, I got an error message `bash: vue: command not found` and I couldn't go any futher.

While I was researching I found the following page,

https://github.com/node-gh/gh/issues/761

and found out that "This request is deprecated as of February 11th, 2020", but what I don't understand is what I should use for instead of this "deprecated request", and how to do it.

Also, in the link above there is a further link, https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143, which presents a list of some alternatives in this kind of issue, but I don't really understand what this means. 
The list for example includes `node-fetch`, `make-fetch-happen`, etc. as "alternative libraries to request", but how do I find out which one is the one to be replaced with `request@2.88.2:`? Also, if I find out which one is the alternative to use instead, what should I do? Just install a particular library, like `npm install node-fetch`?

My OS is Windows 10, and Node.js, which is needed in order to use npm is already installed.

Comment: You can't replace your dependencies' dependencies, you have to wait for them to upgrade. But a deprecation warning isn't the same as the Vue CLI not being installed correctly, I think you're investigating the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not a problem. You've installed vue cli 4.x and vue init is used in vue 2.x ..
to make sure you have vue-cli installed run the following command

```sh
> vue --version
```

to create an app just run the following command.

```sh
> vue create <app_name>
```

then follow the cli steps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I tried ```vue --version```, I got an error ```bash: vue: command not found```. Does that mean I haven't installed Vue and need to do something else besides ```npm install -g @vue/cli```?

Comment: bash: !!!?? didn't you say you were using windows ?! I mean try using the command prompt instead and see if anything changes

Comment: Yes, I do use Windows10, but Git Bash is installed. I've been using Git Bash and it's been working so far, but it suddenly stopped working. I tried the command prompt but still didn't work. I also tried to check the Vue version by ```vue --version```, but got an error ```vue is not recognized as internal or external command```.